# Continuous Deployment using gitlab

Tags: linux, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using gitlab in my local environment. Now I am trying to implement CI for autodeployment process. I followed the tutorial but that tutorial only works on gitlab.com my gitlab addrr is something like this http://192.168.-.-:---/root/test-project.
When I follow the tutorial step by step it works on gitlab.com that means when I add .gitlab-ci.yml file to my root project it triggers the pipeline. But when I add .gitlab-ci.yml file on my local git it doesn't trigger the pipeline as pipeline page shows everytime getting started with pipeline and it seems like i am not pushing it right.
How can I add .yml into my root directory?

Comment: What is it exactly that does not work?

Comment: as on gitlab.com when i add .yml file in the application it shows pause state in pipelines but when i implement this on local gitlab machine it shows nothing and pipeline page always show getting started with pipeline. I have edited my question now you can see the image.

Comment: still unclear what you are trying to do and what error is please update the question with .yml file that you mentioned

Comment: @bhavesh27 hope now you understand it this is the tutorial link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-continuous-integration-pipelines-with-gitlab-ci-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Tell us what did succeed then. Do you have any gitlab-runners up and running and made them available to  your Gitlab instance and is your project allowed to use them ?

Comment: runners use to be done after, the first step is to make pipelines work. I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

> the first step is to make pipelines work. I am confused

This should be easier with [GitLab 13.12](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/05/22/gitlab-13-12-released/#useful-gitlab-cicd-information-in-the-pipeline-editor) (May 2021), which does now include a tutorial:

> ### Useful GitLab CI/CD information in the pipeline editor
>
> Creating your first GitLab CI/CD pipeline can be difficult, especially for those new to CI/CD.
> You might spend time switching back and forth between documentation and GitLab to get your first pipeline configured.
>
> In this release we’ve added a drawer with useful information to the pipeline editor to help guide you through the steps of writing your first pipeline.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_12/drawer.png -- Useful GitLab CI/CD information in the pipeline editor]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipeline_editor/) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/296547).